# integral of $\bigg(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos u}{|u|^{r+1}}du\bigg)^{-1}$

Tags: calculus

For $0<r<2$, how to calculate the following integral:

$\bigg(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos u}{|u|^{r+1}}du\bigg)^{-1}$

According to some book, the answer is $\bigg(\frac{\Gamma(r+1)}{\pi}\bigg)\sin(r\pi/2)$.

Comment: You may  use the Laplace transform to convert the problem into something related with $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{u^\alpha}{u^2+1}\,du$. Then the substitution $u=\tan\theta$, Euler's beta function and the reflection formula for the $\Gamma$ function prove the claim.

Comment: Sorry. Could you please give more details? Thank you.